# Should i use section or fieldset to organize this form?

Tags: html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>Ricetta</title>
</head>
<body>
  <header>
    <h1>Crea una nuova ricetta</h1>
  </header>  
  <form name="nuova_ricetta" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <fieldset>
      <legend>Nuova Ricetta</legend>
    <section id="dati_principali_ricetta">
      <h2>Dati testata ricetta</h2>
      <div> 
        <label for="titolo">Titolo ricetta
          <input type="text" name="titolo" id="titolo" placeholder="Titolo ricetta" required>
        </label>
      </div>
      <div> 
        <label for="descrizione">Descrizione ricetta
         <textarea name="descrizione" id="descrizione" required>Inserisci la descrizione della ricetta</textarea>
        </label>
      </div>
    </section> 
    <section id="corpo_ricetta">
      <h2>Dati corpo ricetta</h2>
      <div> 
        <label for="lista_ingredienti">Lista ingredienti
         <textarea name="lista_ingredienti" id="lista_ingredienti" required>Inserisci gli ingredienti della ricetta separati da una virgola</textarea>
        </label>
      </div>
      <div> 
        <label for="procedimento">Procedimento ricetta
         <textarea name="procedimento" id="lista_ingredienti" required>Indica il procedimento della ricetta</textarea>
        </label>
      </div>
    </section>
    <section id="ricetta_media">
      <h2>Dati Multimediali ricetta</h2>
      <div> 
        <label for="immagini">Caricare immagini della ricetta
          <input type="file" name="immagini" id="immagini" multiple required>
        </label>
      </div>
      <div> 
        <label for="video">Caricare video della ricetta
          <input type="file" name="video" id="video" required>
        </label>
      </div>
    </section>
      </fieldset
      </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Is this code correct? Should i use section and h2 to divide the fields in this form (like in this example) or fieldset with legend? I've followed the example in this page https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Forms/How_to_structure_an_HTML_form
Thank you in advance

Comment: I think "fieldset" is proper way to group the fields instead section when inside a from. "section" is also broader concept. Suppose one section can contain multiple form but a fieldset is not.

Comment: I think it's a matter of preference.

Answer (score 1):

fieldset tags can be very useful for forms specially when you have separate groups of fields. Check this out https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_fieldset.asp
the question is kinda subjective because you know it's up to you and you can organize as well using section tags which you already do